# Print image in PictureBox multipule times

Tags: c#, printing, picturebox

I have a PictureBox control and there is a barcode image in it, I want to be able to add this image multiple times on the same paper.

Now, I can only print one image at every time and I want to add maybe 5 or 10 images and put them together and print them at the same time.

How I can do it??

Comment: Call e.Graphics.DrawImage() as often as you like in your PrintDocument.PrintPage event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can **combine** all images in one image and then print that image. so:

```
int repeatTimes= 10;

Image imageSource = Image.FromFile(@"your image file path");//or your resource..

Bitmap myCombinationImage = new Bitmap(new Size(imageSource.Width, imageSource.Heigh * repeatTimes);

using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myCombinationImage))
{
    Point newLocation = new Point(0, 0);
    for (int imageIndex; imageIndex < repeatTimes; imageIndex++)
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(imageSource, newLocation);
        newLocation = new Point(newLocation.X, newLocation.Y + imageSource.Height);
    }
}

pictureBox.Image = myCombinationImage;
```

Comment: @SzamDev did you try this out, does this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

Create Bitmap with the size of 10 images, draw your barcodes, and put it into PictureBox.